# How to properly flash BIOS from floppy boot?

Tags: boot, flash, bios, floppy

I have a machine with an ECS K7SEM (V3.0C) and I'm trying to flash the BIOS to the newest version so that I can support an AGP 4X video card that I want to install.

So, first, I formatted a floppy disk (1.44 MB) that I had. Then, from Microsoft's website on how to create a bootable floppy, I copied the NTLDR and NDETECT.COM files from the I386 folder on my Windows XP Pro SP3 disk, and pasted it onto the floppy. Then I created a Boot.ini file with copied/pasted stuff from that same website. Then I just copied the flashing EXE and the ROM corresponding to the new BIOS version.

However, the computer will not boot properly from the floppy and will come up with a `Drive A Error... Press F1 to Resume` after POST.

How should I properly go about this?

**EDIT 1:** Just booted it up and the BIOS screen says that the CMOS battery is low as well as something about incorrect memory sizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make your own boot disk. Grab a [pre-made boot disk](http://www.bootdisk.com/) and add the files to that.